# Media Query, change specific TD tag font size via class

Tags: html, css

So I need to change specific td elements font size through media queries.

EXCLAIMER *** Yes I know inline styles are horrible but I have to use them for this piece of work

I have two class .tbold and .tnormal which are for  elements and I want to change their font size when the page because a mobile size e.g. 320px. I know how to do this if I was just using a normal class system or something like bootstrap but when using tables I am not sure how to do this

Here is my code

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Audi MK Advert</title>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'audibold';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        src: url('helper-files/fonts/AudiBold.otf') format('opentype');
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'audinormal';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight:normal;
        src: url('helper-files/fonts/AudiNormal.otf') format('opentype')
      }

      @media all and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 320px) {
        table {
          #tnormal {
            font-size: 10px;
          }
        }
      }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Audi Logo Top Right -->
    <table style="float:right";
            display:block;
            margin-bottom: 10px>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="helper-files/imgs/logo.png">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
    <br>

    <!-- Grey Navbar -->
    <table style="margin:auto">
      <tr style="display:block; background-color:#858585">
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton2.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton3.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton4.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton5.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton6.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton1.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/navbutton7.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 5px"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <!-- Audi Large Photo -->
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td style=align:"center"><img src="helper-files/imgs/header.jpg" style="width:100%"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Body of text -->
    <table style="background-color: lightgray; padding-bottom: 20px; color:grey">
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:15px; padding-top: 35px; font-size:35px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;font-family: audibold">Whats in the name?</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="tbold"; style="padding-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; font-family: audibold">To reflect Ridgeway’s acquisition by Marshall Motor Holdings plc in May of this year, effective from the 1st of November, we have rebranded to Marshall.</td>
      </tr>

      <br>

      <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audinormal">Don’t worry – it’s not all change. Our excellent staff, standards and values will remain the same, ensuring that you receive consistently high levels of service.</td>
      </tr>

      <br>

      <tr class="tnormal">
        <td style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audinormal">The largest expansion acquisition that Marshall Motor Group has made to date, we are now part of a group that operates 103 franchise dealership businesses representing 24 different manufacturer brands across 25 counties in England, with
            a turnover in excess of £2.1bn per annum and 3,500 colleagues; but you, the customer, are still our Number One!</td>
      </tr>

      <br>

      <tr class="tnormal">
        <td style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audinormal">With Marshall Motor Group (who are the 7th largest UK motor group in the UK), we are in a better position than ever to exceed expectations and adopt 106 years of dedicated Marshall expertise, with customer care and impeccable industry
            knowledge at the heart of everything we do.</td>
      </tr>

        <br>

      <tr class="tnormal">
        <td style="padding-bottom:15px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audinormal">Just like always, we’re with you for the road ahead. Welcome to the next destination of our exciting journey. As part of the rebrand <a href="http://www.marshall.co.uk/" style="text-decoration:none; color:black; font-weight: bold;">ridgeway.co.uk</a> will redirect to our new online home of <a href="http://www.marshall.co.uk/" style="text-decoration:none; color:black; font-weight: bold">marshall.co.uk</a> for all things Audi sales, service
            and parts!</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="tnormal">
        <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:35px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audibold">Marshall</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="tnormal">
        <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:35px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: audibold">The new name for Audi in Oxford and Newbury.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Red Labels -->
    <table style="padding:20px; margin: auto">
      <tr style= "display: block">
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/visit.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/about.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/contact.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="helper-files/imgs/livechat.jpg"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <hr>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to change the font size when the display screen becomes 320px?

Comment: yes of specific <td> elements. So I want to have the bold <td> elements shrink but then be bigger than the normal <td> elements

Answer (score 0):

```
    table {
      #tnormal {
        font-size: 10px;
      }
    }
```

You are not using SASS here, right?? This ain't work. Use:

```
    table .tnormal {
        font-size: 10px !important;
      }
```

And change "#id" to ".class"

Comment: I made those changes and it didn't do anything. Doesn't change the font size at all. No you are right I am only using css

Comment: Ok, try to add "!important", as inline style always override other css rules